# How to align 3 divs to the top middle and bottom of a page?

Tags: html, css

I need to align 3 divs to the top, middle and bottom of a webpage Below is my current code.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1hap4k5/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        My Logo
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        My Nav
    </div>
    <div class="base">
       Base
    </div>   
</div>
```

I have tried using table/table-cell method but each section then sits side by side.

The container needs to be fixed and the nav should be vertically aligned.

Any ideas to make is so the logo div is at the top, the nav div is in the middle and the base div is at the bottom?

Comment: No flex solutions please.

Comment: Why not? Please state what you want to support then.

Comment: I am a bit confused... You want the 3 divs to align at the top, middle, and bottom? Will you accept a bootstrap solution?

Comment: Aligned to what? I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want the top div at the top of the page, the nav in the middle and the base at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/r1hap4k5/4/embedded/result/

Comment: Yes like that but with base at the bottom and the nav vertically aligned

Comment: But Chris, I don't want to specify height for each section!

Comment: ...and I'm betting the heights are all flexible too and you don't want overlap....right?

Comment: The when you say vertically aligned nav, do you mean the nav aligns with the side of the opposing divs?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean Chris.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean either lol. Is the base the overflow of the content section? When you say "vertically aligned" where do you expect the Nav to be on a web page?

Comment: I expect the nav to be in the middle of the page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r1hap4k5/12/embedded/result/ Like this maybe?

Answer (score 12):

You could do it with CSS table, I added a `<div>` to each block.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn97ypuu/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: gold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.container .row {
  display: table-row;
}
.container .cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.logo .cell {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.nav .cell {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.base .cell {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row logo">
    <div class="cell">My Logo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row nav">
    <div class="cell">My Nav</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row base">
    <div class="cell">Base</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also make it with flexbox layout.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4Ln2vwm/)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: gold;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="row nav">Nav</div>
  <div class="row base">Base</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created your solution I believe.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="logo">
    My Logo
</div>
<div class="nav">
    My Nav
</div>
<div class="base">
    Base
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: gold;
    position: fixed;
}

.logo{
    background: blue;
    width:100%;
}

.nav{
    background: tan;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /*nudge the div back to the center*/
}

.base{
    background: aqua;
    width:200px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle view of the output](https://jsfiddle.net/r1hap4k5/24/embedded/result/)

I created fixed positions for the base and nav to give vertical alignment.

Comment: Nope, nav is not centered, add more content to it.

Comment: @panthro I edited the answer. Just added a transform to you nav div. I also updated the JSFiddle image.

Comment: @panthro was this what you were looking for?